# Java big list approach to entry coupling

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

**FILE:**
I'm working with a refined csv version of a searchlog file which contains 3.3mio lines of data, with each line resembling a single query and containing various data about that query. 
The entries in the file are sorted ascending by the session / userid.

**GOAL:**
Coupling entries that submitted the same queryterm while belonging to the same userid

**APPROACH:**
I'm reading the csv file line by line, saving the data in selfmade 'Entry'-object and adding these objects to an arraylist. When this is done, I'll sort the list by two criteria with a custom comparator

**PROBLEM:**

While reading the lines and adding the Entry-objects to the list (which takes very long) the program terminates with a OutOfMemoryException "Java heap"

---

So it seems that my approach is too hard on memory (and runtime).
Any ideas for a better approach?

Comment: [sort](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html), first by queryterm, then by userid.

Comment: @MattBall Good. But some users don't have a bash shell available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach itself may be valid, and perhaps the simplest solution is to simply boost the memory available to the JVM.

The JVM will only allocate itself a maximum amount of system memory, and you can increase this value via the `-Xmx` command line attribute. See [here](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp) for more details.

Obviously this solution doesn't scale, and if (in the future) you want to read much bigger files, then you'll likely need a better solution to reading these files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting the lines in memory, you could insert the parsed lines in a database with an index based on the columns defining the duplicity.

Another approach would be to dispatch the lines in many files, each file being named, for example, as the first 2 chars of a sha1 of the concatened columns defining the duplicity. So you'd never have to read more than one file for your ultimate operation because all duplicata would be together.